# Cannot find Izpack 'src' folder

Tags: java, installation, izpack

I am trying to get the source for the  built in panels 'Izpack' provides.....

the documentation says it should be present at
/src/lib/com/izforge/izpack/panels.

but the src folder is missing (not there where i installed Izpack )...

can someone please tell where i can find it

Comment: Do you need the SRC folder to setup an Eclipse project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your question.

The [download page](http://izpack.org/downloads/) for IzPack says:

> If you are interested in the source code then please have a look at the [instructions for obtaining it from Git](http://izpack.org/developers/).

So to get the source code, follow the instructions on [this page](http://izpack.org/developers/). You will need to install **Git**, then you will be able to checkout source code from `git://git.codehaus.org/izpack.git`.

Comment: Problem with this approach is: I cannot setup an Eclipse Project directly on the src/lib folder anymore... Up to the 4.3.3 version we could do this: http://blog.samratdhillon.com/archives/426

Comment: @marcolopes Why not? As far as I understand, all that's changed is the way sources are distributed. As soon as you check them out from the git repository, you can setup Eclipse Project. If Eclipse has Git plugins, you can checkout the sources using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This was the layout of the older IzPack (< 5) code base base. We now use Maven and Git with a completley revamped layout of the source code.

It is still available if you checkout the 4.3 branch in Git.